# puppet apply command without root access in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

I installed puppet client in ubuntu and I am trying to execute my nexus artifact puppet and deployment files after hudson release process without root access.

> How to execute "puppet apply" command without root access in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what you want to do with puppet apply, if you want to edit root owned file/operation, then you need sudo